# Access SQL (or VBA code) to list all tables with at least one attachment field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database with ~150 tables and I need to find a way to list all tables with at least one attachment field. Going and checking by hand would probably be a nightmare :/

Did anyone use / have an Access SQL (or VBA code?) query/ procedure that listed all tables with at least one attachment field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the *TableDefs* collection.

For each *TableDef*, loop the *Fields* collection.

For each *Field*, check the property *Type* (= 101, as I recall) or *IsComplex* = True.

IsComplex is also True for *Multi-Value* fields, but if you don't use these, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Gustav.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on VBA. It prints in immediate (open VBA editor by `Alt` + `F11`, then press `Ctrl` + `G`) messages about tables with Attachment type field.

```vb
Public Sub subTest()
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim td As DAO.TableDef
        Dim fld As DAO.Field
        Dim boolIsAttachmentFieldPresent As Boolean
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        For Each td In db.TableDefs

            If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
                'Debug.Print "Contents of: " & td.Name
                boolIsAttachmentFieldPresent = False
                For Each fld In td.Fields
                    'Debug.Print fld.Name & " of type " & fld.Type
                    If fld.Type = 101 Then
                        boolIsAttachmentFieldPresent = True
                    End If
                Next fld
                If boolIsAttachmentFieldPresent Then
                    Debug.Print "Table " & td.Name & " contains attachment field"
                End If
            End If
        Next td
End Sub
```

All as @Gustav described.

Comment: improve readability with [syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) (code: vba.).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```vb
Public Function ListAttachmentTables()
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim FldsCnt As Long
Dim lngCountLoop As Long

    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Not tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Then
            For Each fld In tdf.Fields
                If fld.Type = 101 Or fld.IsComplex = True Then
                    Debug.Print tdf.Name & " / " & fld.Name
                End If
            Next fld
        End If
    Next tdf
    Set tdf = Nothing

End Function
```

When running `ListAttachmentTables` in immediate window the result was:

```
ASSOC_CLOSING_INFO / Attachments
ASSOC_NAME2 / Attachments
Backup Closing Sharepoint / Documents
Backup Closing Sharepoint / Attachments
CC_Card / Field1
Closing_requests1 / Documents
Closing_requests1 / Delivery_Dates
Closing_requests1 / Total_Package
Closing_requests1 / Attachments
Mail_Requests / group1
Mail_Requests / group2
Mail_Requests / Attachments
MSysResources / Data
UserInfo / Attachments
```

Close to what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You can mark correct answer for future users with same question to find proper solution